# Как выполнить один php файл внутри другого?

Tags: php

Есть папка `dir` в ней лежит файл `1.php`. `1.php` файл содержит в себе вперемешку `html` и `php` код. В общем вот такой путь к файлу `dir/1.php`. А в корне сайта лежит файл `index.php`.

Задача: при открытии файла `index.php` этот файл должен полностью копировать в себя содержимое `dir/1.php` и выполнять, чтобы в адресной строке был адрес на `http://домен.ру/index.php`, а не на `http://домен.ру/dir/1.php`.

Как такое реализовать с помощью PHP? (Апачевскую подмену ссылок не предлагать, не тот случай.)

Comment: Интересно. если Вы про include незнаете, то что твориться у вас в 1.php. Не в обиду сказано)

Answer (score 7):

1. [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
2. [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
3. [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
4. [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

**Листинг index.php**

```
<?php
    include "dir/1.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

index.php:

```
<?php
include '/dir/1.php';
```

Только лучшие ответы. Только без апачевских подмен ссылок. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос был дан выше. Я же лишь поясню значение каждой из четырех функций инклудинга:

```
include  -  самое обычное и стандартное подключение

require  -  если файл не будет найден, то PHP-скрипт закончит свою работу на этом месте

include_once - то же самое, что и "include", только файл подключается только один раз

require_once - то же самое, что и "require", только файл подключается только один раз
```